# Keypath suppressesVideoLayers being observed for AVPlayerItem

Tags: ios, key-value-observing, avplayeritem

I encounter issues with my an AVPlayer. Sometimes (and I cannot define when nor how) the player plays with only the audio and no image.
I could notice that this happens when the keypath "supressessVideoLayers" is being observed.

Would you have any idea why this happens ? And why what seems to be an internal private property seem to be observed ?

This is where I define the keypaths I observe :

```
[self.currentItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];

[self.currentItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty" options:0 context:nil];
[self.currentItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferFull" options:0 context:nil];
[self.currentItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" options:0 context:nil];
[self.currentItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"tracks" options:0 context:nil];
```

Thank you,

Comment: I have exactly the same, if you ever find why, please let me know.